# Method is not properly working when ASP.NET GridView Index gets changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a method which is executed when the page is loaded and when the page of the gridview is changed. This method imports the data, as well setting the rowspans.
The data import is working on every site but the Rowspan only gets set on the first page.
This is my C# Code:

```
 protected void grdvProductChurn_DataBound()
{
    for (int rowIndex = grdvProductChurn.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex += -1)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount <= gvRow.Cells.Count - 8; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (grdvProductChurn != null)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableHeaderCell left = new TableHeaderCell();
        left.Text = "";
        left.ColumnSpan = 2;
        row.Cells.Add(left);



        TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
        totals.ColumnSpan = grdvProductChurn.Columns.Count - 2;
        totals.Text = "Anzahl";
        row.Cells.Add(totals);


    }

}
```

And this is my asp GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdvProductChurn" runat="server" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" autopostback="true"
    BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="30" DataSourceID="DataSource_ProductChurn" 
    AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="960px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridView2"
    Height="119px" OnRowCreated="grdvProductChurn_RowCreated" onpageindexchanged="grdvProductChurn_PageIndexChanged" >
```

Then I also have the method for the onpageindexchanged. It gets executed when I change the page, but the rowspan doesn't work.

```
   public void grdvProductChurn_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdvProductChurn_DataBound();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the page index change event? Also, what's the context of the gridview? Is it in an update panel?

Comment: @AdamDrew It is just a GridView with simple data, you can't edit anything

Comment: Ok, can you add the grdvProductChurn_PageIndexChanged code?

Comment: @AdamDrew It's the one at the bottom.

Comment: Is it possible that any of the conde in OnRowCreated is overriding any display logic *after* the onpageindexchange code?

Comment: Could be, but how can I say which should executed first?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in each and debug. See which is hit first when you change the page. You could also prove that the code within the code is executing correctly.

Comment: So it's like that: when i'm on the first page the Databound gets executed first and on the second page, the rowcreated gets executed and then databound and then the RowCreated again